# Visually Realistic Supercell Modeling

Tags: numerical-modelling, severe-weather, tornado, simulation

Are there any published descriptions of simple equations governing the formation, evolution, and decay of severe storms?  Specifically, I am interested in equations that are able to produce tornadoes with funnel clouds, and output volumetric moisture data.  It does not need to be meteorologically accurate, but should be able to be applied and, coupled with accurate volumetric rendering, produce visually compelling storms.

I have reviewed all [simulation](/questions/tagged/simulation) questions on this site, and have also reviewed both the [WRF](http://www.wrf-model.org/index.php) and [CM1](http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/people/bryan/cm1/) projects.  The former appears to focus more on forecast-relevant prediction (e.g. total rainfall), and the latter lacks documentation and code comments (and is written in Fortran), making it useless for adaptation in my own simulation.

Comment: Have you tried using WRF or CM1? Both are capable of simulating supercells given appropriate settings and grid resolution.